# E-infinity operads explicit examples

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, operads

I was looking for particular and explicit examples of $E_\infty$-operads. I know the $E_\infty$-operad defined by Smith in http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0004003, and the Barratt-Eccles operad, but it is hard to find in the literature something concrete. Thanks!

Comment: I suspect that the meaning of "concrete" will depend on what you want your operad to act on.

Comment: I'm not thinking in a particular application, i want to see how other people are using this notion, and learn from it.

Comment: In that case, the most obvious one to study should be the Little $\infty$-cubes operad defined by May in "The Geometry of Infinite Loop Spaces". As the title suggests, this operad acts naturally on infinite loop spaces.

Comment: Definitely the works of May in the early 70's is a good place to look. The linear isometries operad is another example.

Comment: I suggest that you take a look to Segal's paper *Categories and cohomology theories*. Although he does not use operads explicitely, I think it probably contains the best proof of the main theorems about the $E_\infty$-operad. After you've understood that you can look into May's *The Geometry of infinite loop spaces* and similar papers

Comment: Please, Denis, that makes no sense: you don't learn about operads from a paper that never mentions them, and I could write for hours about the comparison of infinite loop space machines, which is not what the question is about.  There are quite a few $E_{\infty}$ operads defined in a variety of categories.  Just in spaces there are many others besides those already mentioned.  A recent reference describing some of the virtues and defects and some of the roles of various examples is http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/PAPERS/Final1.pdf